# Vuex: Sending arguments to actions from within vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

below is one of my vuex actions.

```
updateProds: (context, data) => {
        axios.get(data.url)
        .then((response) => {
             context.dispatch( -----  );
            
        })
    },
```

inside the Promise return, I want to dispatch another action but want to pass in the response from this action.  How can I do that?

Comment: _"inside the Promise return"_ which promise return? Can you give an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your action returns a value or a promise that resolves with the value you want, eg

```js
actionOne: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
  // do something async, commit values, etc
  return actionResponse
}
```

then you can keep chaining promises like so

```js
axios.get(data.url)
  .then(({ data }) => context.dispatch("actionOne", data))
  .then(actionResponse => context.dispatch("actionTwo", actionResponse))
```

Note the implicit return value from the arrow functions. The `.then()` method always returns a new promise that resolves with the `return` value.

In longer form, this looks like

```js
axios.get(data.url)
  .then(({ data }) => {
    return context.dispatch("actionOne", data))
  })
  .then(actionResponse => {
    return context.dispatch("actionTwo", actionResponse))
  })
```